# Tenant based Configuration and Operational Store configuration

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, identityserver4

We have multi-tenant applications, so we have to use the operational and configuration store data inside that particular tenant DB only. Is this possible to configure instead of the below code?

This will be run only one time while launching the id server app, but I want to register the below service while based on tenant request, so only current tenant DB will store the operational and Configuration store tables with values.

```
// configure identity server with in-memory stores, keys, clients and scopes
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
    .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers())
    // this adds the config data from DB (clients, resources)
    .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
    {
        options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
            builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
    })
    // this adds the operational data from DB (codes, tokens, consents)
    .AddOperationalStore(options =>
    {
        options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
            builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));

        // this enables automatic token cleanup. this is optional.
        options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
        options.TokenCleanupInterval = 30;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to separate Db for different "tenant"? You can separate configurations on the "Client" level.